# Представить или предоставить документы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, паронимы, выбор-варианта

Подскажите, какой вариант является верным?

На грамоте.ру и других сайтах написано, что со словом "документы" сочетается только слово "представить" в значении 'предъявить'. А что если мы отдаем документы для оформления кредита или ипотеки? Тогда по значению ближе слово "предоставить".

К.ф.н. Ольга Северская в статье http://rus.1september.ru/view_article.php?id=200902311 пишет, что оба варианта допустимы: "документы разрешается по языковым нормам как представлять («предъявлять, подавать»), так и предоставлять («отдавать в чье-то распоряжение»)".

Прошу помочь разобраться в вопросе

Comment: Ольга Северская уже во всем разобралась. В чем же вопрос?

Comment: Будет ли вариант "предоставить документы" предпочтительнее в том случае, когда документы действительно отдают?

Comment: На этом сайте с 2016 года есть много данных по этому вопросу: см. в Поиске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я просмотрела официальные сайты налоговых, пенсионного фонда, где часто встречается данная формулировка. Везде "представить документы". В словарях паронимов, на сайте грамота.ру, русскийязык.ру дается четкое разграничение, в сочетании с какими словами необходимо употребить слова "представить" и "предоставить". Важным показателем для меня является оттенок смысла в слове "предоставить" - 'отдать в пользование', 'позволить распоряжаться'. (Квартира, заём, кредит, слово, возможность, свобода), во всех источниках одни и те же слова. Думаю, что в разговорной речи допустимы оба варианта, но для официальных документов лучше употребить слово "представить". Логику тех, кто говорит "предоставить" я понимаю, но нормативно все же это не закреплено.

Вывод: представить документы

Comment: Согласен в общем с Вашим ответом, но думаю, что (а) в разговорной речи под "предоставить документы" часто понимается "предоставить копии документов" и (б) случай передачи документов на хранение и/или в залог является в этом отношении пограничным.

Comment: Везде "представить документы" ==> Вероятно, тем самым утверждается, что суть вопроса  — показать документы, доказать требуемый статус (представить). А передача документов в пользование инстанции (предоставить) — дело вторичное, процедурный вопрос, это остается за кадром.

Comment: @М_Г Трудовую книжку в случае приёма на работу не просто предъявляют, а отдают. Но это не означает, что работодатель может ею распоряжаться. Это я называю "пограничным случаем".

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта допустимы, но в разных ситуациях. В подавляющем большинстве случаев документы **представляют** в подтверждение каких-либо прав или оснований для действий. Если же целью является ознакомление с документами, и это в интересах того, в чьих руках документы оказываются, то их **предоставляют** (напр. в архиве) кому-то или в чьё-то распоряжение.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, требуя предоставить документы, банк не оставляет сомнений в том, что документы придется передать банку. Представить документы — только предъявить их банку, а придется ли их там оставить, не оговорено.