# Представление и предоставление доказательств

Tags: паронимы

Предоставление — передача чего-либо в полное распоряжение, в чью-либо пользу.
Представление — доставка чего-либо куда-либо, предъявление.
Взято отсюда: [https://paronymonline.ru/П/271](https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%9F/271)

Предъявить — показать, представить в подтверждение чего-либо.
Взято отсюда: [https://sinonim.org/t/предъявление](https://sinonim.org/t/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Во многих источниках я слышал, что правильно говорить именно "представьте доказательства", а не "предоставьте доказательства". Однако представить доказательства это всё равно что их предъявить, т.е. показать, представить в подтверждение. Слово "предоставить" закладывает другой смысл, который заключается в том, что какая-то вещь отдаётся в полное распоряжение кому-то.

Допустимо ли говорить и писать "предоставьте доказательства", если речь не о том, чтобы просто их мимолётно показать, а о том, что эти доказательства теперь будут использоваться ещё где-то, уйдут куда-то в базу данных и т.д. Мне кажется, что слово "предоставьте" тут больше подходит.

Comment: Можно посмотреть здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440139/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be/440142#440142 (Пред(о)ставление документов и информации - как правильно?)

Comment: И еще вот здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443935/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b/443938#443938 (Представить или предоставить документы?) Пользуйтесь поиском по сайту.

Comment: Спасибо большое, прошу прощения за повторный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одно из значений слова ‟представить” – это показать, продемонстрировать [(ссылка на Викисловарь)](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C). В данной ситуации (в сочетании с ‟доказательство”) оба слова близки по значению и оба подходят.